# query that subtracts sum of one column from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to the following in my database

```
+----+----+----+---------------------+
| id | a  | b  | date_created        |
+----+----+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 22 | 33 | 2014-07-31 14:38:17 |
|  2 | 11 |  9 | 2014-07-30 14:40:19 |
|  3 |  8 |  4 | 2014-07-29 14:40:34 |
+----+----+----+---------------------+
```

I'm trying to write a query that subtracts `sum(b)` from each `a`. However, the values of `b` included in `sum(b)` should be only those that are earlier than (or the same time as) the `a` they are being subtracted from. In other words, the results returned by the query should be those shown below

```
22 - (33 + 9 + 4)
11 - (9 + 4)
 8 - (4)
```

is it possible to calculate this in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , x.a - SUM(y.b) 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.date_created <= x.date_created 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select id, a, a - (select sum(b) 
                     from My_TABLE T2 
                    where T2.date_created <= T1.date_created)
  from MY_TABLE T1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
select t1.a - ifnull( sum(t2.b), 0)
from myTable t1
left outer join myTable t2 on t2.date_created <= t1.date_created 
group by t1.a
```

Note that the table is joined to itself to access two different sets of information.

Edit:

I think you probably want to group by the date_created like:

```
select t1.date_created, t1.a - ifnull( sum(t2.b), 0)
from myTable t1
left outer join myTable t2 on t2.date_created <= t1.date_created 
group by t1.date_created, t1.a
```

Comment: Nah, nonsense. `ifnull()` is not needed; I just overlooked you need the dates to be "less than *or equal*". Fixed now.

Comment: Because of the 'or equal' bit, an outer join is superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbae0/12)**

```
SELECT
   id,
    a - (@total := @total + b) as Total
 FROM
    (SELECT *, @total:=0
     FROM  my_table
     ORDER  BY date_created asc) AS Base
```